# how to solve "Your Connection Is Not Private" on katalon

Tags: automated-tests, testng, testcase, katalon

While running katalon testcases on windows. I am facing

> "Your connection is not private"

How can I bypass this in headless Chrome?

I have tried to use web UI for acceptInsecureCerts but still not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, as seen [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/your-connection-is-not-private-message-when-using-chrome-to-run-test-cases-katalon-7-2-1):

- Under Project Settings > WebUI > Chrome add a new entry with name = `acceptInsecureCerts` with boolean value of True
- try with name = `args` with list type and value = `[--ignore-certificate-errors]`

If you wish to do that programmatically, try

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```